# Cursor through html in VS lags

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If I have a decent size asp.net page open in Source view, and hold down the Up key or Down key to scroll through it, it will periodically get "stuck". It will stop on a line for a few microseconds, and you can see the screen flash, like it's trying to catch up with what it's trying to do behind the scenes. In my two-monitor setup, I'm working in monitor 2, and you can see the icons on the desktop on monitor 1 flash. It's annoying because I invariable overstep lines and have to move back and forth, constantly correcting for the lag. Any idea what it's doing as I cursor through the code? Anything I can turn off to stop this from happening? (Slowing down my key repeat rate is not an option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possibly the property pane - this was a big issue in VS2005, and VS2005SP1 not only added a feature to turn this off, but turned it off by default, however it looks like they've removed the option to turn it off in VS2008.

Scott Guthrie had a post on [HTML Source Editing Performance in VS2005 SP1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/html-source-editing-performance-improvements-in-vs-2005-sp1.aspx).

Closing the property pane may well solve the issue if you don't really use it all that much.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it didn't help. I never us properties, so I closed it, but it's still "sticking".

Comment: This helped. The noticeable lag in the html source editor has gone away. Thanks!